# $modalInstance.close Stopping $location.path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a modal that is opening up and information is put into it.  If you click save the information is stored and the modal closes.  All works, but if I try to change location after or before the modal closes it doesn't work.  If you take out the $modalInstance.close the location change works, but you're stuck with the dumpy modal :[  Why?

Controller parts:

```
var onSaveFinished = function (result) {
            $scope.$emit('quiverApp:customerProfileUpdate', result);
            $modalInstance.close(result);
            $location.path('/rentalAgreements/new');
        };
$scope.save = function () {
        if ($scope.customerProfile.id != null) {
            CustomerProfile.update($scope.customerProfile, onSaveFinished);
        } else {
            CustomerProfile.save($scope.customerProfile, onSaveFinished);
        }
    };
```

Modal Part:

```
    <form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="save()" show-validation>
    <div class="modal-header" id="goAwayy">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="clear()">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myCustomerProfileLabel">
            <span ng-show="state.is('customerProfile.new')">Create a Customer Profile</span>
            <span ng-show="state.is('customerProfile.edit')">Edit the Profile of {{customerProfile.firstName + ' ' + customerProfile.lastName }}</span></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-left form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="field_firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="field_firstName"
                    ng-model="customerProfile.firstName"
                    >
        </div>


    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid || editForm.$submitted" class="btn btn-success">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>&nbsp;<span>Save</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could try using the modal `result` promise callback to do the location change:

```
$modalInstance.result.then(function(){
    $location.path('/rentalAgreements/new');
});
```

Comment: Didn't work either :{

Add in: `var onSaveFinished = function (result) {
            $scope.$emit('quiverApp:customerProfileUpdate', result);
            $modalInstance.close(result);
        };
            $modalInstance.result.then(function(){
                console.log('fire');
                $location.path('/rentalAgreements/new');
                console.log('gone');
            });`
I get both logs and the page doesn't go.

Comment: but that shouldn't be defined inside the function. It gets triggered by the close method

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: move the code I gave you outside of the save function

Comment: It is right... `var onSaveFinished = function (result) {
            $scope.$emit('quiverApp:customerProfileUpdate', result);
            $modalInstance.close(result);
        };
----------------------------------
        $modalInstance.result.then(function(){
            console.log('fire'); $location.path('/rentalAgreements/new'); console.log('gone');
        });`

Comment: sorry, very hard to read code blobs in comment blocks. Suggest you create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: The modal closes, but the page doesn't go.  The fire and gone display.  It is as if when the modal closes the browser stays on the page -  as if someone clicked it.